Telegram link with draft_text unicode issue
I trying to use telegram link to profile with draft_text
https://core.telegram.org/api/links#public-username-links
https://t.me/someuser?text=привет

But I have unicode issue. 
I tried encodeUriComponent, converting to unicode (original text is unicode too), but I always have wrong encoding inside of text message input
How to prepare text properly?
